# Not able to move my JavaScript snippet to external file using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/_mfjKP76Mro?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-CroDWZxHTy7K9pdzCBptV9&t=170) but I'm having trouble getting the JavaScript example to work.

I tried [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide) from W3Schools and it works. But when I move the code to an external file, it stops working. I see no warnings or errors in the Flask terminal or Chrome's console.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/demo')
def demo():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
integrity="sha384-TlQc6091kl7Au04dPgLW7WK3iey+qO8dAi/LdwxaGBbszLxnizZ4xjPyNrEf+aQt"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}); // END .ready event.
</script -->

<script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
<!-- script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script -->

</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

`script.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}); // END .ready event.
```

Comment: Why do you have `<script src="static/js/script.js"></script>`? Just try with `<script>`

Comment: @roganjosh I don't quite follow do you have a more comprehensive example code outside of StackOverflow that I can look at that describes what you are referring to?  Isn't the below code usually the Flask way to do things? `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: Post your solution as an *answer*, not as edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code solved things for me. Turns out that this syntax `<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js">` is necessary for Flask external file JavaScript to work in Chrome. While `<script src="myFile.js">` only worked for me in Firefox.

Also I had a bunch of commented out horizontal HTML rulers in my original code. That might have interfered with some commented out and disabled script tags that I left for experimentation and evidence purposes. `<script>` only tag had an overflowing behavior that interfered with previously disabled and commented out script tags such as `<script></script>`.

I cleaned them out perhaps they were part of the conflicting issue, perhaps they weren't, I don't know for sure.

> Also don't forget to pause **Ghostery extension** addon in your Chrome web browser when debugging JavaScript code in console mode. It can create extra errors beyond your control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
integrity="sha384-TlQc6091kl7Au04dPgLW7WK3iey+qO8dAi/LdwxaGBbszLxnizZ4xjPyNrEf+aQt"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- script src="../static/js/script.js" -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
<p onclick="$(this).hide();">Inline JavaScripting.</p>

</body>
</html>
```